# Fastest way to insert 30 thousand rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, performance, insert, query-performance

I have to insert 30000 ids in a temporary table `##MyTempTable` that has only one column (`ID int`) and I would like to know which way I could do it fastest.

I have tried 30000 normal inserts

```
insert into ##MyTempTable (ID) ...
```

I have tried

```
insert into ##MyTempTable (ID) (
 select 1002000 union all 
 select 1002001 union all 
 select 1002002 ...
```

The fastest way so far has been:

```
insert into ##MyTempTable (ID)
values
(1002000),(1002001),(1002002),(1002003) ...
```

Because this type of insert only accepts a maximum of one thousand rows, so then I repeated that insert 30 times.

Would you be able to help me?

Comment: What programming language? There is a bulk API, but any advice depends - on the environment. C# has a SqlBulkCopy class for that stuff, for example.

Comment: @TomTom - I need to do it in C#. I tried using SqlBulkCopy, and it was much slower. I suppose I didn't use it very well. I tried to create a DataRow for each ID and this loop took ages in comparison to the pure SQL statements. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What about not using a data row at all. We do SqlBulkInsert over objects. I reach about 75k inserts per second on lower end hardware. Yes, that is 75000.

Comment: @TomTom - would you mind giving me an example of your object that you made the SqlBulkInsert?

Comment: Simple class with properties. The trick is the SqlBulkCopy implementation that uses a special provider. All that is on the internet though and NOT a question to ask here - programming is StackOverflow. Google has details. "SqlBulkCopy with objects" is something you could use.

Comment: I only asked the question here because I thought I had to do it as a SQL statement so the programming language didn't matter. Now it's becoming a programming question if using SqlBulkInsert is the way to go. Anyway, if somebody one day find that there is a better way to do this in SQL only they can post it here and it can help other people. - Thanks @TomTom

Comment: I posted a question on stackoverflow with my code:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028657/fastest-way-to-insert-30-thousand-rows-in-a-temp-table-on-sql-server-with-c-shar

Answer (score 5):

If you are really just trying to insert 30000 ID values that increment by 1, starting at 1002000, I highly doubt you'll be able to rig up anything in C# that will be faster than something like this:

```
INSERT ##MyTable(ID)
  SELECT 1001999 + n FROM
  (
    SELECT TOP (30000) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
    FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
    ORDER BY s1.[object_id]
  ) AS x;
```

In my lowly Windows VM on a Mac host this occurs sub-second.

For other ideas about generating sets / sequences without looping (e.g. a numbers table may be even faster), see this blog series:

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3

If the values are defined and not some incremental sequence (e.g. 30,000 values you somehow coerced into a DataTable), then you can consider using a table-valued parameter. First, create this type in your database (you just do this once):

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.MyIDs AS TABLE(ID INT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Now have a stored procedure that accepts this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TakeMyIDs
  @m dbo.MyIDs READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT ##MyTable(ID) SELECT ID FROM @m;
END
GO
```

Now call your stored procedure from C# and pass the DataTable as a parameter:

```cs
// assuming an active connection object, conn,
// and a populated DataTable called dtIDs:

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.TakeMyIDs", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter tvp1 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m", dtIDs);
tvp1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Dispose();
```

Comment: Hi - no, the ids I have to insert aren't incremented. They are specific ids and can be any ramdom value. The ones I posted there were pure coincidence, because I used a set of examples as test. But they won't be incremented :-(

Comment: @Jenninha then please explain where they're coming from and how your code is currently holding 30,000 values - are they in a DataTable or some other collection? A comma-separated list? A text file?

Comment: They are ids of a set of search results from a user search that is done outside my application. To be honest I haven't defined how I will receive them yet, so now my test is only by having an array with 30000 ids that I will have to insert in a temporary table in SQL Server.

Comment: Instead of an array put them in a DataTable. If you don't know how to do that then it will be a question more appropriate for StackOverflow I think. Once your values are in a DataTable, this answer should help.

Comment: I did it, I put it in a DataTable, but it was too slow I believe because of my loop to create the DataRows.
I will post my SqlBulkCopy insert in a question on StackOverflow and then everyone can see where I might have done something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I believe the SQL Server side will be fast, but if you're looping 30,000 times in your application to put those values in one at a time, it isn't going to matter what you do on the SQL Server side - the database can't make your code any faster.

Comment: That's why I believed that I should keep trying to improve my query as when I simply build my SQL string (programatically) like in my question and it works faster then building a DataTable.

Comment: I posted a question on stackoverflow with my code:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028657/fastest-way-to-insert-30-thousand-rows-in-a-temp-table-on-sql-server-with-c-shar